# How do you specify html helper to have the runat server attribute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

As per question says. Specifically i want the html.beginform() to have the runat="server" attribute.

Reason is that inside the form I'm placing the asp.net login control, which requires the form element to be runat server.

Thanks heaps.

Rwendi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can forget about this attribute in ASP.NET MVC 3. It cannot be used. Don't use server side controls in an ASP.NET MVC application. They cannot work. Either use a legacy WebForms ASPX view or if you want to work with ASP.NET MVC you will have to replace the ASP.NET Login control with ASP.NET MVC specific things. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application usnig the built-in wizard and look at the AccountController and the corresponding LogOn view.

Comment: Care to elaborate more on why no server side controls in asp.net mvc application?

Comment: Because those controls rely on ViewState and PostBack models => things that no longer exist in the ASP.NET MVC pattern. The ASP.NET MVC pattern is quite different than classic WebForms.